# Python Selenium can't click unique element ID links

Tags: python, selenium

The goal here is to find all the links on the page, click them one by one and extract a piece of data from each.

```
links = scrapeFrame.find_all('a', id=re.compile("MiniProfileLink_"))
```

That piece of code returns

```
[<a href="/members/?id=27164571" id="MiniProfileLink_27164571" onmouseout="HideMiniProfile();" onmouseover="MiniProfileLink_OnMouseOver(27164571);" target="_top">Daniel Adams</a>, <a href="/members/?id=17535970" id="MiniProfileLink_17535970" onmouseout="HideMiniProfile();" onmouseover="MiniProfileLink_OnMouseOver(17535970);" target="_top">Ben Affleck</a>]
```

Here is where the problem occurs:

```
for link in scrapeFrame.find_all('a', id=re.compile("MiniProfileLink_")):
    python_button1 = browser.find_element_by_id('MiniProfileLink_' + str(x))
    python_button1.click()
```

I got an error saying that no such element exists.

Comment: So, did you check the value of str(x)? Provide a minimal and complete code example.

Comment: Yeah I believe that's my first mistake the value of x = 0.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `link.click()` inside the loop?